# how to create tar file so that files at placed at root folder of tar.gz file

Tags: linux, extract, tar

I need to create targ.gz file and contents of file should be at root folder

say. I want angle and Simple files at root of tarfile shown at bottom. Any suggestions. I tried as below but extra folder is created at root

```
tar -zcvf tarfile.tar.gz -C /example/tarFile .
./
./angle.txt
./Simple.jar

tar -zcvf tarfile.tar.gz -C /example/tarFile .
./angle.txt
./Simple.jar
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try this

```
tar -czvf tarfile.tar.gz /example/tarFile
```

after creating tar file use `cp` or `mv` command to move anywhere you want.

Comment: the command worked but within that dir I need to run this tar -czvf tarfile.tar.gz *